# Material UI remove Menu padding

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there any way to remove top and bottom padding from Menu component?

Tried to set padding to 0 in PaperProps and also in makeStyles but when I inspect the element on browser it still shows 8px default padding on top and bottom.

Here's the code if it helps:

```
<Menu
    className={classes.menuSearchContainer}
    PaperProps={{
        style: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            width: "270px",
            paddingTop: '0px',
        },
    }}
>
<Input
    className={classes.menuSearchInput}
    type="text"
/>
```

Comment: Sure, I edited original post. I don't know does it help much because I need to remove default padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

target the `list` class from `Menu` classes prop.

```
<Menu
  {...other props}
  classes={{list:classes.list}}
>
  {...meuItem}
</Menu>
```

and `useStlyes` will be:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    list:{
      padding:'0'
    }
  }),
);
```

Checkout a [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-20lk5)

Answer (score 1):

use `MenuListProps`:

```js
<Menu
    className={classes.menuSearchContainer}
    PaperProps={{
        style: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            width: "270px",
        },
    }}
    MenuListProps={{ sx: { py: 0 } }}
>
<Input
    className={classes.menuSearchInput}
    type="text"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<MenuItem dense=true />
```

From Materiul-UI dense : If true, compact vertical padding designed for keyboard and mouse input will be used.

This might be the issue.

Comment: I have Input field inside Menu component, so MenuItem is not the component I need to remove padding. And Input does not have dense option.

Comment: Try adding these props to the components pt=0, pb=0. As per https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/